# warnings when casting to void**

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I'm trying to cast a struct pointer to a `void**` for a function that takes a `void**`;

```
typedef struct {
  uint64_t   key;    // the key in the key/value pair
  void      *value;  // the value in the key/value pair
} HTKeyValue, *HTKeyValuePtr;

HTKeyValuePtr payload = (HTKeyValuePtr)malloc(sizeof(HTKeyValue));
int success = (HTKeyValuePtr) LLIteratorGetPayload(i, (void**) &payload);
```

gives me the warnings:

```
hashtable.c:161:19: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
hashtable.c:161:19: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

What's going on? How do I fix this?

p.s. sorry if this is a dup of any other question. There were a lot of similar questions but I couldn't find one that fit my situation and that I understood.

Comment: **Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`!**

Comment: @H2CO3 yeah, in this case I shouldn't have. Habit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int success = (HTKeyValuePtr) LLIteratorGetPayload(i, (void**) &payload);`

You're assigning a pointer into an int...

In addition, google tells me the first argument to `LLIteratorGetPayload` should be a `LLIter`, which turns out to be a `typedef void*`. I'm guessing `i` is an integer. That's the reason for the first error.

Comment: btw, i is a LLIter. It was just the HTKeyValuePtr cast.

Comment: Oh well. There's only so much I can guess... Now I see that `LLIteratorGetPayload` returns an `int`. This explains the twofold error.

Comment: Yup. I forgot the return type, corrected it on the left and forgot to change it on the right.